# Какую выбрать тему диплома бакалавра по Android?

Tags: android

Преподаватель сказал, что я могу выбрать сам тему для диплома и попросил принести список идей из 10-20 тем, чтобы их обсудить. Я хочу сделать такой диплом, чтобы можно было потом его использовать как часть портфолио и показывать будущим работодателям. Это может быть как локальное приложение, так и какой-то клиент-сервер. Посоветуйте пожалуйста идеи не сильно сложные в реализации для новичка, но чтобы они были интересные и актуальные.

Comment: У меня создается такое впечатление, что преподаватель просто хочет, чтобы вы для него составили список тем, которые он выберет для своей преподавательской деятельности.:) То есть он свою работу возложил на вас. Как-то несерьезно от студента требовать предоставить список из 10-20 тем. Максимум, что можно требовать от студента, это 2-3 темы.:).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow нет, преподаватель просто дает полную свободу выбора, он лишь скажет, что лучше делать, а что лучше не делать в дипломной работе, но он тоже хочет, чтобы это была работа от души, а не унылое творение от безысходности. Он даже приводил несколько примеров, просто решил, что будет лучше делать то, что хочу я. А мне нужен маленький толчок в генерировании идей :)

Comment: Полная свобода выбора - это не эквивалентно тому, чтобы предоставить 10-20 тем.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну это же не утверждение, что надо расписать детально столько именно тем. Он имел ввиду самые простые идеи, которые мне нравятся, чтобы более детально подумать какие можно расширить, а какие только и останутся лишь идеями. А я лишь хочу, чтобы каждый озвучил пару своих идей, возможно приложений, которых ему не хватает итп...

Comment: Пиши для андройда что-нибудь на p2p  хотя бы месенджер

Comment: @korolariya это одно из предложений преподавателя, только там была p2p игра. Есть какие-то более конкретные предложения? :)
И что мне сделать, чтобы пользователя вновь могли писать ответы на этот вопрос?

Comment: @Kostya ничего не сделаешь потому как вопрос не соответствует правилам сайта, тебе на форумы нужно или в гугл

Comment: Вопрос действительно не подходит по формату сайта, т.к. на него нельзя дать краткий и верный ответ. Но вы можете пообсуждать это в чате, репутация вам уже позволяет. На мой взгляд, лучше всего подходит чат [Околотехнические вопросы](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26433/). Заходите туда, напишите мне через `@NickVolynkin`, обсудим.

Comment: Если есть желание сделай что то с гугл картами. К примеру запоминало твой проделанный путь за весь день(работает в фоне) и потом типа ты сегодня проделал путь длиной в 5км, просмотр истории и т.д. Ну это так, скорей всего таких приложений куча, это то что в голову пришло)

Comment: @g8214435 классная идея :)